# How to have submenus collapsed until they are clicked?

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu, add-submenu-page

I have couple of main admin menus and sub-menuse underneath them.

```
Main menu1
      Sub menu 1
      sub menu 2
      sub menu 3
Main menu2
      Sub menu 1
      sub menu 2
      sub menu 3
```

Like above.

I use following code block to create the main menu1

```
function register_myplugin_admin() {
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Main menu1', 'textdomain' ),
        'Main menu1 ',
        'manage_options',
        '/myplugin/includes/admin-menu.php',
        '',
        plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ),
        6
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_myplugin_admin' );
```

Since all these are menu appear as open, i am thinking of the possibility of collapsing these menus to the parent level

i.e Main Menu1 & Main Menu 2 are displayed, and upon user click of main menu 1 or main menu 2, the relevant section gets expanded / visible to the user.

is there any way to achieve this through WordPress actions / hooks or filters?

Comment: edit your question to show the code which defined a main menu.

Comment: edited the question to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

I use plugin called ubermenu and have paid for the deluxe version of it. You can customize all types of things within a menu that's much more extensive than built-in functionality.  I think the cost of ten bucks or so is well worth it.  Add plugin----> Ubermenu in search field then install and activate. Then customize to your heart's content.

Comment: No, I want to do this without using an external plugin as a dependency.

Comment: I guess. I don’t know if you can